# wrong DM1 multipacket

Tags: j1939

I have gathered the can Data of a Scania G380 Truck using stm32 mcu.
there is a problem with DM1 faults. according to j1939-73 when dm1 data length is over than 8 bytes it would be packetized by TP.DT (pgn 0xebff) announced by a TP.CM (pgn 0xecff), but I face with these data, packetized in a strange manner :

```
18ECFF00     DATA: FF FF 7D 7D FD FF FF FF
18EBFF00     DATA: FF FF 7D 7D 3C FF FF FF 
18EBFF00     DATA: FF FF 7D 7D FD FF FF FF 
18EBFF00     DATA: FF FF 7D 7D 3C FF FF FF
18EBFF00     DATA: FF FF 7D 7D FD FF FF FF
```

it seems it doesn't follow the protocol.

another strange problem is that dm1 faults were broadcast in single packet repeatedly instead of being packetized in TP.DT pgn. for example I have this log:

```
18FECA27     DATA: 00 17 09 07 34 22 74 7D   TIME: 425447
18FECA10     DATA: 2F 21 43 3C 37 43 06 55   TIME: 425474
18FECA2F     DATA: D1 FF 1F FF FF FF FF FF   TIME: 425594
18FECA0B     DATA: 38 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00   TIME: 425626
18FECA00     DATA: 00 FB 00 FB 3F FC FF FF   TIME: 425634
```

could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
18ECFF00     DATA: FF FF 7D 7D FD FF FF FF
18EBFF00     DATA: FF FF 7D 7D 3C FF FF FF 
18EBFF00     DATA: FF FF 7D 7D FD FF FF FF 
18EBFF00     DATA: FF FF 7D 7D 3C FF FF FF
18EBFF00     DATA: FF FF 7D 7D FD FF FF FF
```

This looks like some garbage/default values. I think Scania is not using DM1 messages to report DTCs over CAN bus.

Comment: Do you know any way to read DTCs? we sniff obd port while a VCI3 connected, it seems scania has it's own obd protocol, it doesn't follow the standard.